# Fit background image parent div to image size

Tags: css, background-size

I'm wondering if there is any way in CSS to fit a background image's parent div to the image size? For some reason when I  use:

background-size: cover;

My image becomes blurry because it is being scaled somehow...

Comment: I would be tempted to do it in javascript. You could resize the div on the page load.

Comment: You mean like `background-size: contain`? There is no CSS way to set an element to the size of it's background image...none at all.

Answer (score 1):

Funny. I started writing an article about a related idea the other day. You can do it fairly easily, but it's counter-intuitive.

I just threw together a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/denmch/pen/mVgXKW). Here's the relevant CSS:

```
.bear {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82724/bear.jpg)
              no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 56.75%;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

You can tweak that as you need to. I set it up for absolutely centered content.

Padding and margins need a common reference to maintain consistency, and that reference is the width of the parent element. First there's the viewport, then the body, and so on. Each element refers to its parent's width to determine its own margins and padding.

You can use this to your advantage if you know the aspect ratio of your background image by doing a little math (or you could use `calc()` if you want to and don't need to support Opera Mini).

Divide the height by the width of the image. In my example, the image's height is 56.75% of the width.

We can then take that number and apply it either to `padding-top` or `padding-bottom`, and as the parent scales, the padding in the child will scale with it, maintaining the aspect ratio.

If you want to put things in that div, you either have to do some annoying math (subtracting the height of the children from the padding -- blech!), or you can instead absolutely position a child div to hold the contents.

At this point there's a lot of playing around and customization depending on your needs and goals.

One caveat is that the content can easily overflow, so you want to plan well, and possibly set a min-height to mitigate that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use background-size: 100% auto; which will not distort the image...

Comment: I think the question is about making the element match the aspect ratio of the background image. `background-size: 100% auto;` will always fill 100% width, but may or may not fill the height of the element. The element will maintain whatever height it has and will either cut off the top and bottom or show gaps.

Comment: I'm sorry, but `cover` and `contain` also do. as the element changes, `cover` will also ensure that there are never any gaps (i.e., that the element's background is always covered), and `contain` will ensure that the full image is visible (i.e., that the image is always contained inside the element). `100% auto` just ensures that the width is covered, but the height may or not be. All three maintain aspect ratio for the image, but none can affect the aspect ratio of the element itself.